# Why does the POST stop working when setting state in useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why does the `POST` stop working when trying to set `State` using `useEffect` and `fetch`?

In this first example, I can see in the `POST` log in the Chrome console and print in Flask:

React:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import ArrowUpwardIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowUpward';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

export default function Heater(props) {

  const [status, setStatus] = useState({
    "id": props.id,
    "name": props.name,
    "pin": props.pin,
    "setpoint": 1
  });

  function incrementSetpoint() {
    setStatus(previousValue => {
      return {
        ...previousValue,
        "setpoint": status.setpoint + 1
      };
    });
  };
 
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/heaters', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(status)
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .catch((error) => (console.error(error)))
  });
     
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{ props.name }</h1>
      <div className="inputs-container" style={{ marginBottom: '2ch' }}>
        <TextField label="Setpoint" value={ status.setpoint } />
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={ incrementSetpoint }>
          <ArrowUpwardIcon></ArrowUpwardIcon>
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Flask:

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/heaters', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def heaters():
    """Control heaters and return the current heater configuration."""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.json)
    return jsonify(request.json)
```

Now, if I comment out the `console.log` and use `setState` instead, it causes and infinite loop in Flask.

```
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/heaters', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(status)
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      // .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .then((response) => setStatus(response)) // New line here
      .catch((error) => (console.error(error)))
  });

  ...
```

After reading some other posts, I decided to add an empty array to `useEffect`. This stops the infinite loop. I can see that `setStatus` is working by adding `console.log(status)`. **However, the POST is no longer working**.

```
  ...
 
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/heaters', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(status)
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      // .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .then((response) => setStatus(response)) // New line here
      .catch((error) => (console.error(error)))
  }, []); // Empty array added here

  console.log(status); // New line here to confirm setStatus works
  
  ...
```

On the initial startup, I can see the `POST` log in the Chrome console and print in Flask. After it has loaded, the `POST` does not work. Any ideas on what is causing the issue?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"the POST is no longer working"_? It's really unclear why you're posting `status` and then also setting it from the response

Comment: To check whether state variable `status` got updated, one may choose to use: `useEffect(() => { console.log('status changed to: ', status); }, [status]);` (instead of simply `console.log()`, we place it within an use-effect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `useEffect()` bound to an empty array, it only executes once on the first run.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // fetch code here
}, []);
```

I'm guessing that you want to run it again on every `status` update?

If that's the case, bind `useEffect()` to your `status` state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // fetch code here
}, [status]);
```

Thing is, if you `setStatus` in that same `useEffect()` hook, you end up in the infinite loop - because it runs again after the `status` is updated.. and then again.. and again.

So you want to create a different state heaters `[heaters, setHeaters]` then `setHeaters` after you fetch, rather than `setStatus` again.

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState({
    "id": props.id,
    "name": props.name,
    "pin": props.pin,
    "setpoint": 1
  });
const [heaters, setHeaters] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/heaters', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(status)
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => setHeaters(response))
      .catch((error) => (console.error(error)))
  }, [status]);
```

That way, whenever you `incrementSetpoint()` the `status` will update, the `fetch` will run, and `heaters` is set.

Finally, you see your fetched data by using another `useEffect()` bound to the `heaters` state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(heaters);
}, [heaters]);
```

This should be the convention.

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thank you. I also came across this YouTube video today that explains ```useEffect``` very well. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dH6i3GurZW8

Comment: Glad to have helped!